# How do I listen to multiple udp ports using twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I've written a server using Python and the Twisted library that communicates via UDP. This all works well.

What I would like to do is extend that server so that it can accept messages on multiple UDP ports simultaneously (I use the different ports to segregate the information returned, and it's less about the source of the request). I've tried to do the simplest thing first as a test - I wrote code that looks like this:

```
reactor.listenUDP(port, handler)
reactor.listenUDP(port+1, handler)
```

(The first line is the one originally in my server; the second line is the 2nd port to listen to.)

When I run that, I get the following:

```
File "./rspServer.py", line 838, in mainLoop
  reactor.listenUDP(self.args.port+1, udpHandler)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 347, in listenUDP
  p.startListening()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 86, in startListening
  self._connectToProtocol()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 106, in _connectToProtocol
  self.protocol.makeConnection(self)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 665, in makeConnection
  assert self.transport == None
AssertionError
```

I take from this that I can't add a second UDP listener, but that's exactly what I'd like to do (actually, to make a total of 18 listeners - it's a long story). Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: you could pass several handler instances instead of the same one

Comment: Rakis has left a correct answer to your question, but this is also a bug in Twisted - even if it's an error, you should never get such an unhelpful error message (and you should never see an assertion error, period).  Please file a bug at http://twistedmatrix.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each call to listenUDP() needs a unique handler instance. Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks for the help. I'm now able to have my 18 ports actively being listened to.